# Need help in Python requete

Tags: python, sql, mariadb

I'm trying to execute this :

```
cursor.execute("UPDATE 'produit' SET 'Top 1'=%s, 'Top 2'=%s, 'Top 3'=%s WHERE 'Id'=%s " % (n[2],n[1],n[0],i+1))
conn.commit()
```

but i get the following error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use
>   near ''produit' SET 'Top 1'=1, 'Top 2'=3, 'Top 3'=5 WHERE 'Id'=1' at
>   line 1

Comment: I suppose 'Top 1', 'Top 2' are the column name which is confusing because there is a TOP N command in sql as well. Either replace single quotation marks -->' with this -->` or completely remove them and try again.

Answer (score 0):

```
SET 'Top 1'=%s, 'Top 2'=%s, 'Top 3'=%s
```

I believe **SQL** is looking for field names in place of where you have `'Top 1', 'Top 2', 'Top 3'`. If you are trying to update the 1st, 2nd, and 3rd columns, you cannot do so in this way.

https://mariadb.com/kb/en/sql-99/update-examples/

Answer (score 0):

Use backtics for table and column names that foolishly include spaces or other punctuation.

Not

```
"UPDATE 'produit' SET 'Top 1'=%s, ...
```

rather:

```
"UPDATE `produit` SET `Top 1`=%s, ...
```